# Attaching JSON to Web Page Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a web page which I want to send some JSON data down with. Currently, I put necessary information within hidden input tags, then I make a call to a webservice to retrieve extra data. I would like to know what ways are available to merge the calls together.

Comment: Why use input fields? Can't you just make a single XHR call passing all the data at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about merging the calls together, but I don't see any reason for putting JSON data in hidden form fields. I'd just put it in a `script` tag as a JavaScript literal:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myJSONData = {
    // ....
};
</script>
```

Since [JSON](http://json.org) is a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax, you can safely assume valid JSON is a valid JavaScript object literal.

For example, if your JSON is:

```
{ "Towel": "Always know where it is", "Answer": 42, "Author": "Douglas Adams"}
```

Then this is what the `script` tag would look like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myJSONData = { "Towel": "Always know where it is", "Answer": 42, "Author": "Douglas Adams"};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean 'merge', do you intend to send your pre existing json to the webservice to get results?

If so, you could use a callback in the onload event to achieve the appearance of a single 'call'.